# How do you convert a UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to UInt8?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

The question is really simple, but somehow I don't know how to do it:

How do you convert a UnsafeMutablePointer to UInt8?

I tried converting it like this:

```
UInt8(theUnsafeMutablePointerVar)
```

but it gave me the following error: *Cannot find an initializer for type 'UInt8' that accepts an argument list of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to convert the pointer to the correct type first
(a pointer to `UInt8`) and then you can access the memory it points to:

```
let u8 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(theUnsafeMutablePointerVar).memory
```

In **Swift 3,** a void pointer from C is imported to Swift as 
`UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, and one can read the pointed-to data
with

```
let u8 = theUnsafeMutablePointerVar.load(as: UInt8.self)
```

Comment: `UnsafePointer<UInt8>(theUnsafeMutablePointerVar)` just doesn't work for me. `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)'`. Same if I try `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` rather than `UnsafePointer`.

Comment: Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Comment: @HughHughTeotl: It still works for me. What type has theUnsafeMutablePointerVar in your case?

Comment: @Lneuner: What type has `theUnsafeMutablePointerVar` in your case?

Comment: @HughHughTeotl it doesn't work if you directly substitute the casting in a function. Just try assigning it to a constant as in the answer: `let u8 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(theUnsafeMutablePointerVar).memory` and then use `u8` wherever required. It helped me. Weird!

Comment: Ahhh that's it! Very strange, but doing it in a two-stage process like that works fine. (Sorry I missed your ealier message btw)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pointee` property in the latest Swift.