# Cast UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to my struct type

Tags: pointers, struct, casting, swift2

In my swift code I use the peertalk objective-c library using a bridging-header.

In a delegate method I get some payload in a parameter with the type of `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`.

How can I cast the payload to my struct type in Swift so I can use the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess referencing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626410/how-do-you-convert-a-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-uint8)

```
struct YourStruct {
    var name : String
}
var structInstance = YourStruct.init(name: "Jose")

func delegateMethod(voidPtr : UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    //CONVERSION HERE
    let myStruct = UnsafePointer<YourStruct>(voidPtr).memory
    print("\(myStruct.name)")
}
delegateMethod(&structInstance)
```